# Convert nested list with tuple elements into dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, tuples, nested-lists

I have a nested list with tuple inside which looks like this:

```
[[(0, 0.01581311),
  (1, 0.00818853),
  (2, 0.01093196),
  (3, 0.95393395),
  (4, 0.0111324545)],
 [(0, 0.0026787873),
  (1, 0.001387138),
  (2, 0.9921792),
  (3, 0.0018690126),
  (4, 0.0018858392)],
 [(0, 0.013304136),
  (1, 0.0068892473),
  (2, 0.96115804),
  (3, 0.009282486),
  (4, 0.009366056)]]
```

And I would like to convert it into dataframe where columns name will be the first element in round brackets (in this case it is numbers 0 1 2 3 4). Or maybe there is a way that allows not to display the first element before comma and will get something like this:

```
[[(0.01581311),
  (0.00818853),
  (0.01093196),
  (0.95393395),
  (0.0111324545)],
 [(0.0026787873),
  (0.001387138),
  (0.9921792),
  (0.0018690126),
  (0.0018858392)],
 [(0.013304136),
  (0.0068892473),
  (0.96115804),
  (0.009282486),
  (0.009366056)]]
```

Comment: Please include your attempts and the code you have written to get to your goal. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for a list of what a good question should include. Thank you!

Comment: [`DataFrame.from_records()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html) could work, if you convert the inout into a list-of-tuples, and throw away the column numbers.

Comment: Your example column numbers 0,1,2,3,4 are a bad example, solutions could just ignore them. Can you edit the example column numbers to be something other than consecutive integers starting at 0?

Answer (score 0):

This function should give us our expected result:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def list_to_dataframe(lis):
    lis = np.array(lis)
    shape = lis.shape
    LEN = len(lis)
    series = []
    if len(shape) == 3:
        # 3D list
        columns = lis[0,:,:][:,0].astype(np.int)
        get_section = lambda l, i: l[i,:,1]
    else:
        # 2D list
        columns = np.arange(0, shape[1]).astype(np.int)
        get_section = lambda l, i: l[i,:]
    # prepare the series
    for i in range(0, LEN):
        sec = get_section(lis, i)
        series.append(pd.Series(sec))
    df = pd.DataFrame(series)
    df.columns = columns
    return df
```

## How I am using:

```py
l1 = [[(0, 0.01581311),
  (1, 0.00818853),
  (2, 0.01093196),
  (3, 0.95393395),
  (4, 0.0111324545)],
 [(0, 0.0026787873),
  (1, 0.001387138),
  (2, 0.9921792),
  (3, 0.0018690126),
  (4, 0.0018858392)],
 [(0, 0.013304136),
  (1, 0.0068892473),
  (2, 0.96115804),
  (3, 0.009282486),
  (4, 0.009366056)]]

l2 = [[(0.01581311),
  (0.00818853),
  (0.01093196),
  (0.95393395),
  (0.0111324545)],
 [(0.0026787873),
  (0.001387138),
  (0.9921792),
  (0.0018690126),
  (0.0018858392)],
 [(0.013304136),
  (0.0068892473),
  (0.96115804),
  (0.009282486),
  (0.009366056)]]


list_to_dataframe(l1)
list_to_dataframe(l2)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not much different from @enke's, but it prepares an empty data frame, retrieves the given multiple list in a loop process, creates a temporary data frame, and adds it to the empty data frame.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

lst = [[(0, 0.01581311),
  (1, 0.00818853),
  (2, 0.01093196),
  (3, 0.95393395),
  (4, 0.0111324545)],
 [(0, 0.0026787873),
  (1, 0.001387138),
  (2, 0.9921792),
  (3, 0.0018690126),
  (4, 0.0018858392)],
 [(0, 0.013304136),
  (1, 0.0068892473),
  (2, 0.96115804),
  (3, 0.009282486),
  (4, 0.009366056)]]

dfs = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(np.array(lst).shape[0]):
    df = pd.DataFrame(list(lst[i]))
    dfs = dfs.append(df.T.iloc[1], ignore_index=True)

0   1   2   3   4
0   0.015813    0.008189    0.010932    0.953934    0.011132
1   0.002679    0.001387    0.992179    0.001869    0.001886
2   0.013304    0.006889    0.961158    0.009282    0.009366
```